# Provide different Dock and Tray icons for Electron based App on Mac?

Tags: macos, electron, macos-catalina, dock, tray

I was researching a bit and so far only found resources about template images but not a definite guide. I'm building an Electron app (Electron 8.0). I do have customized icons for dark as well as regular mode.

I know that I can provide high-dpi icons like this:

- tray_icon.png
- tray_icon@2.png

It's similar within the `icns` file for the Dock icon. I was wondering whether I can do the same for dark vs. regular mode icons.

How do I need to prepare/name my icons so that macOS Catalina picks up different icons for the Tray as well as the Dock whether it is running on regular or on dark mode?

Do I need to implement some logic to switch the icons programmatically? How would such logic be execute when my Electron app isn't running but the theme is switched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically, this can be easily implemented

```js
const { nativeTheme } = require('electron')

nativeTheme.on('updated', function theThemeHasChanged () {
  updateMyAppTheme(nativeTheme.shouldUseDarkColors)
})

// set tray & dock images here
function updateMyAppTheme(isDark) {
  tray.setImage(isDark? darkTrayImagePath : lightTrayImagePath)
  dock.setIcon(isDark? darkDockImagePath : lightDockImagePath)
}
```

Relevant docs:

- [Supporting macOS Dark Mode](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/mojave-dark-mode-guide)
- [nativeTheme](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/native-theme)
- [Tray](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/tray)
- [Dock](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dock)

Comment: Thanks! Those links are the ones I found, too. Is programmatically the only way? How would I execute a script and switch the Dock icon when my app isn't running? There must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Looking at [Apple's guidlines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/icons-and-images/app-icon/), it appears they don't mention anything about this. Do you know any apps which do this (change the dock icon even if the app is dead)?

Comment: I found [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/providing_images_for_different_appearances) which seems to imply that it's possible to bundle different appearances in Xcode. But I don't think that will work with an Electron app.

Comment: Further discussion and research seems to indicate that there isn't really a way to do it declaratively on macOS.